# Trying to run pyspark in Jupyter notebook getting error java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run pyspark in Jypyter notebook its giving me following exception:
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o190.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2, localhost, executor driver): java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /10.209.34.114:50701

Things I have tried:

- I have verified I am only running one instance of spark
- Tried upgrading to the latest version of spark
- There is no problem with code; I think the problem is how bash profile is setup.

Here is my configuration (bash profile on MaxOSX)

```
export SPARK_VERSION=`ls /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/ | sort | tail -1`
export SPARK_HOME="/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/$SPARK_VERSION/libexec"
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH

export SPARK_PATH=~/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="jupyter"
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"
export PACKAGES="io.delta:delta-core_2.12:0.1.0"
export PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--packages ${PACKAGES} pyspark-shell"
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
alias snotebook='$SPARK_PATH/bin/pyspark --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.$
```

here is the sample code I am running:

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("spark test").getOrCreate()
columns = ['id', 'dogs', 'cats']
vals = [
     (1, 2, 0),
     (2, 0, 1)
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(vals, columns)
df.show()
```

Complete stack trace:

https://pastebin.com/i43vMLms